# Picking certain set of dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I tried to find the solution everywhere but I couldn't find the way to solve this problem. Suppose I have multiple dictionaries in a list:

```
[
    {"Type": "A", "Name": "Sam"},
    {"Type": "A", "Name": "Apple"},
    {"Type": "B", "Name": "Sam"},
    {"Type": "C", "Name": "Apple"},
    {"Type": "C"}
]
```

What I need are the dictionaries that have `'Type' == 'A'`.

The result I am trying to get is:

```
[{"Type": "A", "Name": "Sam"}, {"Type": "A", "Name": "Apple"}]
```

Is there any way I could achieve this? Any help or any direction into solving this problem would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through your list and take all dictionaries with a `Type` of `A`:

```
>>> data = [{"Type": "A", "Name": "Sam"},{"Type":"A", "Name":"Apple"},{"Type": "B", "Name": "Sam"},{"Type":"C", "Name":"Apple"},{"Type":"C"}]
>>> [d for d in data if d.get('Type') == 'A']
[{'Name': 'Sam', 'Type': 'A'}, {'Name': 'Apple', 'Type': 'A'}]
```

Using [dict.get()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict.get#dict.get) ensures that it works for dicts without the key `Type`:

```
data = [{"Type": "A", "Name": "Sam"},
        {"Type":"A", "Name":"Apple"},
        {"Type": "B", "Name": "Sam"},
        {"Type":"C", "Name":"Apple"},
        {"Type":"C"},
        {}]
>>> [d for d in data if d.get('Type') == 'A']
[{'Name': 'Sam', 'Type': 'A'}, {'Name': 'Apple', 'Type': 'A'}]
```

because:

> `get(key[, default])`
>
> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for.  You are awesome.

Comment: It should be noted that this will throw a KeyError if a dictionary doesn't have a 'Type' key.

Comment: @JaredGoguen Thanks for the hint. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a
[{'Type': 'A', 'Name': 'Sam'}, {'Type': 'A', 'Name': 'Apple'}, {'Type': 'B', 'Name': 'Sam'}, {'Type': 'C', 'Name': 'Apple'}, {'Type': 'C'}]
>>> b = [x for x in a if x['Type']=='A']
>>> b
[{'Type': 'A', 'Name': 'Sam'}, {'Type': 'A', 'Name': 'Apple'}]
```

Comment: This will throw a `KeyError` if a dictionary doesn't have a 'Type' key.

Answer (score 0):

```
[d for d in d_list if d.get('Type') == 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is almost definitely not the most pythonic way of doing it, but if you need a quick and dirty solution, I believe it works.

```
 def filterDictionaries(dictionaries, type):
      filteredDicts = []
      for dict in dictionaries:
          if 'Type' in dict:
             if dict['Type] == type:
                filteredDicts += dict
      return filteredDicts
```